# Firebase realtime database, Check if firebase database value exists or not?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase real-time database but I needs some help to solve this problem.
 Here is my code:

```
  let usersDB = Database.database().reference().child("user/\(username)")
        usersDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                self.lblUserAvailability.text = "Not Available"
            }
            else {
               self.lblUserAvailability.text = "Available"
            }
        })
    }
```

What I want, if a user is already exist in database it should go to "snapshot.exists()" statement but in my case it always go to the else statement. 
My database structure is:

[image]

> user
>
> > -LXa4s3d9BrGqDThdWU-
> >
> > > username "rashid55"

Comment: remove this `child("user/\(username)")` and add this instead `child("user")`

Comment: But I want to check a specific value I mean a specific username 
Please check this image to get better idea 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eCSK.png

Comment: @Rashid Latif check my answer below, it will work

Comment: Let me check please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to listen to the "user" node and query for the name that you are searching

```
let usersDB = Database.database().reference().child("user").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(username)
    usersDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            self.lblUserAvailability.text = "Not Available"
        }
        else {
           self.lblUserAvailability.text = "Available"
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Shahzaib Qureshi